# WARNING in ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm5/ng2-charts.js 230:54-72 "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, angular7, ng2-charts

I am using `ng2-charts` in `Angular 7` app and having warning

> WARNING in ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm5/ng2-charts.js 230:54-72
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

error in `VS Code`

[image]

error in `browser`

[image]

What could be the reason and how to resolve it?

Comment: What are you using ng2-charts in your code. Code you please update the code ?

Comment: I am using `ng2-charts`, `chart.js` and `@types/chart.js`. Code is posted but I think it is not related to code. It may be related to some `import` or `export` module

Comment: May be because of version compatibility? have you tried out other versions?

Comment: No, not yet. OK try to figure via different versions. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It worked. version `2.2.4` was giving this error but `2.2.3` worked fine.

Comment: Version `2.2.5` also works fine.

Comment: @croc Surely they fixed that bug in that `2.2.5`

Comment: I think they just reverted the changes from `2.2.4` ([bug report](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/750)). Sadly this hasn't been fixed in `2.3.0` yet as well.

Comment: I should have found this link earlier. This bug is in 2.3.0 as well.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### Update: May 2021

Recently I have used `ng2-charts@2.4.2` in `Angular v11` and it's working fine. You may try with the latest version

```
npm install ng2-charts@latest // it will automatically install latest version
```

### Older

`ng2-charts v2.2.4` has this bug as lots of users are reporting that so down-grading to `ng2-charts v2.2.3` is fine until it is fixed in the future releases.

```
npm install ng2-charts@2.2.3
```

Comment: Downgrading works fine. Just `npm install ng2-charts@2.2.3 --save` and wait for it to update

Comment: @WasiF I have angular version 5.2.1, i tried above solution but it didn't work. Please guide

Comment: @WasiF It's same error as mentioned in above question. We tried with version 2.2.0, 2.2.3 & 2.2.5 but getting same error. We have Angular CLI 1.7 and angular core 5.2.1

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani it might be the reason of angular version because if you read question of I have mentioned the angular version on 1st line that it is `Angular 7`

Comment: Downgrading failed with this logs
```PS D:\projects\twit-auto\ui> npm install ng2-charts@2.2.3
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "__ngcc_entry_points__.json": name cannot start with an underscore```

Answer (score 2):

Right, you have to do `npm install ng2-charts@2.2.3 --save`
Also, check into your package.json for `"ng2-charts": "2.2.3",`
I also faced same issue but previously I had `"ng2-charts": "^2.2.3",` so I removed caret (^). It means "Compatible with version" it will install major version. But use "Fixed version" if you don't want to change version of package on each installation.