# ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm5/ng2-charts.js 230:54-72 "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am trying to integrate the [ng2-Charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) while compiling it is throwing the error on the console and browser.

As i took the reference of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371427/warning-in-node-modules-ng2-charts-fesm5-ng2-charts-js-23054-72-export-%C9%B5%C9%B5de) downgrading the version of the ng2-charts also throws the error in the console and the browser.

[image: Error Browser Image]

[image: Console Warning]

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ChartsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I am using "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0", version of the charts now

Comment: What version of angular you use ?

Comment: **Angular CLI: 7.3.8 , Node: 12.7.0 , Angular: 5.2.1** @TonyNgo

Comment: did you try version  2.2.5 ?

Comment: yes tried with 2.2.5 version too it's throwing the same error @FatemeFazli

Comment: @Santhosh Facing same issue. Did you get the solution?