# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chart.js' in /node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015'

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, ng2-charts

I am encountering the error:

**ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.js**

**Module not found: Error: *Can't resolve 'chart.js'* in /node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015'**

I did "npm install --save ng2-charts". Could you help me to understand why this error is thrown?

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~8.2.9",
"@angular/common": "~8.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.2.9",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.9",
"@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/forms": "~8.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.9",
"@angular/router": "~8.2.9",
"@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.6.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"firebase": "^7.6.0",
"ng2-charts": "^2.2.3",
"rxjs": "~6.4.0",
"sweetalert2": "^9.5.3",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1" }

"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
"@angular/cli": "~8.3.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.9",
"@angular/language-service": "~8.2.9",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.15.0",
"typescript": "~3.5.3" }
```

Error in broswer

[image]

Comment: when exactly does this error happen??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WARNING in ./node\_modules/ng2-charts/fesm5/ng2-charts.js 230:54-72 "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371427/warning-in-node-modules-ng2-charts-fesm5-ng2-charts-js-23054-72-export-%c9%b5%c9%b5de)

Comment: Solved, For Angular 7 or greater version use



```npm install ng2-charts@2.2.3 --save```

AND
  ```npm install chart.js --save```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**ng2-charts** is just an angular wrapper for **Chart.js** library. Hence the latter also needs to be installed separately.

> npm install --save ng2-charts
>
> npm install --save chart.js

Answer (score 0):

Try installing chartjs higher version, For me an older version was installed
Try "npm install chartjs@3.7.1"

Answer (score 0):

The following needs to be added to angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"
],
```

Note that Chart.js starts with a capital letter. chart.js might work on some platforms but not on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I use chart.js@4.4.1 and  Aangular 17. I build the app with Mac and deployed on Ubuntu. But during the deployment build it fails. It produces the error

```bash
Error: Can't resolve 'node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js' in '/var/www/html/admin'
```

Now when I check the ubuntu server, the file is not found, but when I check the mac, the file is found.

```bash
ls 'node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js'
```

Here is the problem. If you look inside the node_modules, the file chart.js has a lowercase 'C'. So MacOS, the node_module files arent case-sensitive but in Ubuntu, they are case-sensitive.

Solution:
Go to your angular.json file and change the file to lower-case inside the scripts array. Problem solved!

```
'node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js'
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm on Angular 17.0.3. and I finally got this figured out. I had downloaded a pre-built Angular theme and it would not compile. In my case the issue was that Chart.js was being imported in this manner:

import 'chart.js/dist/Chart.js';

This didn't appear to be the correct format in my experience. Usually when I see it in Angular it's something like this:

import { ModuleName } from 'module';

I eventually found out that if I changed the import to the following, which is also a tad bit different than I'm used to, it works just fine:

import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

Hope this helps someone out as I spent a lot of time working on this.