# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chartjs' even after installed it

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js

```
    "chart.js": "^4.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
```

```
import React from 'react';
import second from 'react-chartjs-2'

const BarChart = () => {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen bg-gradient-to-br from-violet-400 via-white to-violet-400 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg: px-8">
      BarChart
    </div>
  );
};

export default BarChart;
```

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chartjs'`

iam trying to setup the chart.js  after install  chart.js it show error

Comment: I finally got this working. See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638363/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-chart-js-in-node-modules-ng2-charts-fe/77643143#77643143